# Organizational memberships - multiple purchase?

Tags: civimember

Is it possible to have a membership option for an organization where they can purchase multiple memberships at once? If so, what is the best way for those memberships to be attached to their staff?

Comment: Are you familiar with using 'inherited memberships' via 'relationships'? does that provide mostly what you need? https://docs.civicrm.org/user/ca/latest/membership/defining-memberships/

Comment: Yes, I know about those. The issue is that they want an organization to be able to sign up for a specific number of memberships. For instance, they have 7 staff members, so they purchase 7 memberships at once.

Comment: what cms? if drupal i might still think of using 'inherited' memberships but set up webform to ask the user to specify 'how many' and use that to then show 'that number' of contact fields, and use that in a formula field to set the price.

Comment: or again, in webform you could, i believe, do each membership separately, with a single payment, but not sure how that would flow through to civi - and not much point speculating if you are not using drupal, or not interested in using w_c

Comment: Yes, we're using Drupal. They already have webform civi installed, so that works. It's already used in the membership process.